# Socket.io, get two responses from client then run code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io

I am wanting to make the answer validation only fire off once two unique responses are received from the client side.

```
var nrecieved = 0;
var responses = {}; // Socket id to response

function finish(){
   // Loop through users in game and send them their responses
   for(var id in responses){
        if(responses.hasOwnProperty(id)){
             // Send the response
             io.to(id).emit('updatePlayer', responses[id]);
        }
   }
}

socket.on('playerCorrect', function (data) {
    nrecieved++;
    responses[socket.id] = data;
    answerValidation(nrecieved);
});    

socket.on('playerWrong', function (data) {
    nrecieved++;
    responses[socket.id] = data;
    answerValidation(nrecieved);
}); 

console.log(nrecieved);
function answerValidation(value) {
    nrecieved = value + value;
    console.log(value);
    if(nrecieved == 2){
        finish();
        dataRequest();
    } 
}
```

Problem is I cant really use nrecieved++; in those socket events otherwise it wont count correctly. Is there a way to fire off the counter if the clients playing the game had to choose their answers and that would fire off the socket event and then ++?

Comment: This is what it seems like you are trying to do: 1. Receive any kind of response (wrong or right) 2. increase the received counter for each response no matter what kind. 3. Send a response to everyone when any 2 responses have been received (wrong or right)? Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: You are correct. It is just about checking if two answers have come through. One from each player

Comment: only one from each player?

Answer (score 0):

```
var nPlayers = 2; // Total number of players to process at a time
var responses = {}; // Socket id to response

var finish = function(){
   // Loop through users in game and send them their responses
   for(var id in responses){
        if(responses.hasOwnProperty(id)){
             // Send the response
             io.to(id).emit('updatePlayer', responses[id]);
        }
   }
}

var answerValidation = function() {
    // number of players reached
    if(Object.keys(responses).length === nPlayers){
        finish();
        dataRequest();
    } 
    // reset responses
    responses = {};
}

var registerAnswer = function(id, data) {
    // check for existing response from this player
    // disallows overwriting answers until processed
    if(!responses.hasOwnProperty(id) {
        responses[id] = data;
        answerValidation();
    }
};

socket.on('playerCorrect', function (data) {
    registerAnswer(socket.id, data);
});    

socket.on('playerWrong', function (data) {
    registerAnswer(socket.id, data);
});
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to be getting through to running     if(Object.keys(responses).length === nPlayers){
        finish();
        dataRequest();
    }

Comment: can you post the full file?

Comment: I'll test on my node server a bit later